# Application token,consumer key and consumer secret of my QB application

Tags: quickbooks-online

I want the application token,consumer key and consumer secret for my quickbooks application created using my trial account.But I could get only the client key and client secret.Should it be a paid version else where can I get the keys for my quickbooks application?

Answer (score 0):

Quickbooks stopped supporting OAuth 1.0. Currently, they are supporting OAuth 2.0. That's why you see only client key and client secret.

Refer this - https://developer.intuit.com/hub/blog/2017/08/03/quick-start-quickbooks-online-rest-api-oauth-2-0